# Recaptcha 404s Errors

Tags: recaptcha

What could I do to try and troubleshoot a re-captcha that had previous been working but now returns a 404 when trying to access the javascript file.

I don't think it's a coding issue because they were up this afternoon.

For what it's worth both my sites using re-captcha have the same issue.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reCaptcha service may be experiencing issues. I have multiple websites that are all receiving 404 errors. I know for sure at least 2 of them were working a couple of hours ago.

This is the error I am seeing: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recapcha_1-XXXXXXXX.js

I've also just found a few other posts with people experiencing the same issue.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I wish they had a service status site to check for outages and whatnot. I guess if others are having issues though it can't be someone messing with firewall settings or anything like that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's very unfortunate. I looked around for a "Service Status" but couldn't find anything. I am considering using something local to the server in the future. It

Comment: I just found that same file 404ing for me as well.  I googled recaptcha 404 and this came up.  It's unfortunate, but  thanks to you, I didn't have to waste a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a global problem at the moment. Twitter feed for reCaptcha has many, many tweets.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, using Chrome's console I went to the "Sources" tab and edited the URL.  Just change recapcha_1-XXXXXXXX.js to recapcha_ajax.js and save the change.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure that you have version 2 in web config recaptcha api.

Version one doesn't run properly

add key="recaptchaApiVersion" value="2"

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you answer to one question, try to explain a little bit your answer. In your case, there are more answers so expose Pros and Cons of your P.O.V.

Comment: Dear I explained in context as required, whoever has this issue can easily get this fix understood, cheers

Comment: I already edit you answer as it was not clear. It is not an issue if it is clear or not, is an issue that there are more answers, your P.O.V. is not matching with the answer voted, so please, expose why your reply is better or not and why.